# Combine GetMessage and PeekMessage

Tags: c++, winapi, getmessage, peekmessage

I intend to create a small application with 2 windows, a normal window with controls and a 3D window, rendered with DirectX. For 3D window `PeekMessage()` is recommended because it doesn't wait after checking the messages but for normal windows (no 3D rendering) the `GetMessage()` function is used to avoid processor senseless overuse.
So, when the 3D window is active (`WM_ACTIVE` message received) I want to use `PeekMessage()` and when the normal window is active I want to use `GetMessage()`.

The main loop would look like this:

```
NormalWindowActive = false;
Window3DActive = false;
MSG msg;

while (TRUE) {
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if (NormalWindowActive) {
        if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    } else {
        RenderWindow();
    }
}
```

In the messages handler of these windows I have the `WM_ACTIVATE` message:

```
HWND NormalWindow, Window3D; // These windows are global vars

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // ...
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        if (wParam!= WA_INACTIVE) {
            if (hWnd == NormalWindow) {
                NormalWindowActive = true;
                Window3DActive = false;
            } else {
                Window3DActive = true;
                NormalWindowActive = false;
            }
        }
    break;
    // ...
}
```

What I expect from the TaskManager is to show the application busy (~50% processor use) when the 3D window is active and not so busy when the normal window is active (~5% processor use). I only see 50% processor use when both windows have lost focus but I see 0-5% processor use when any of them is active. I believe that there should be a difference, so I am not sure if this is really working (or even possible). The 3D window is rendered and the normal window responds to events, too, but the processor use confuses me. I just don't want this to affect the FPS of the 3D window.

Comment: Instead of trying to deduce what's happening from task manager, why not simply put in a counter and count how many times you're using GetMessage vs. PeekMessage?  Then you can test it a while and break in with a debugger and examine the counters.

Comment: I'll do that right now. Thanks

Comment: Add some tracing statements with OutputDebugString(), this is hard to debug with breakpoints.

Comment: Well, in like 3 seconds of application running, the counter (inside the main while) has led to 136. I suppose this is a god sign

Comment: The case should be `WM_ACTIVATE` (rather than `WM_ACTIVE`).  Is that just a typo here?  Also, do both windows share this window proc?

Comment: WM_ACTIVATE, sorry. Yes, both windows share the same WndProc

Comment: Does your `RenderWindow` function use vertical synchronization?  That would limit the rate at which your message loop runs.

Comment: Try using a while loop for PeekMessage.

Comment: Have you fixed this?  Perhaps you could show where NormalWindow gets set?  And how you know its the proper value?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the normal window is active, you should check whether the 3D window is inactive. You can also use `WaitMessage` instead of `GetMessage` because it saves you from duplicating code.

For example:

```
if (Window3DActive)
    RenderWindow();
else
    WaitMessage();
```

Your problem seems to be that when the normal window is inactive, the message loop doesn't wait even though the 3D window is inactive.

If you decide to use `WaitMessage`, you should also loop on `PeekMessage` because there might be more than one message in the queue and `WaitMessage` doesn't return until there a new message arrives.